# How to sendkeys unicode character VBA - without clipboard

Tags: excel, vba, unicode, sendkeys

I need to insert chatacter 'ü' to the web page with VBA via SendKeys.

- Application.SendKeys "ü" does nothing

Then I tried to send ALT+code combination:

- Application.SendKeys "%(0252)" does nothing for ALT+0252
- Application.SendKeys "%(129)" does nothing for ALT+129

I cannot (don't want to) use clipboard and paste it. It is a nice workaround but not applicable in this case.

No, API doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about using `chr(252)`?

Comment: Another approach: Inject Javascript into the page and insert from there

Comment: Are you able to send other chars? Is it only ü that causes trouble? FYI I can use `SendKeys "ü"` to send ü to Notepad so the problem may be with your receiving application and not with SendKeys.

Comment: @xidgel That did not work for me in Excel (trying to send keys to a worksheet), but it did work using `Application.SendKeys "+´u", True`

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns: Application.SendKeys Chr(84) for "T" works, Application.SendKeys Chr(252) for "ü" not.

Comment: @xidel: it works for Application.SendKeys "ü" when default win language is set for German.

Comment: BUT why combination with ALT does nothing? Application.SendKeys "%(0252)"? Manually (by humane typing) it works nicely...

Comment: @kabarto ALT codes have to be typed on the numeric keypad, but AFAIK `Application.SendKeys` doesn't send digits from the numeric keypad.  The digits along the top of the keyboard are different than the digits on the numeric keypad

Comment: @kabarto Have you tried `Application.SendKeys "+´u", True`?